# Centering texted div with absolute position

Tags: html, text, position, absolute

I need few lines of text to be centered horizontaly and verticaly on image, i read a lot in internet but i didn't helped me any of solution.

HTML:

```
<div id="textContainer">
    Preparing for important meeting? <br />
    <b>Drink some coffeee!</b> <br />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/me2octq.jpg" />
</div>


<div id="baner">
    <div class="imgBaner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgBaner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 460px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/5pijCrS.jpg) no-repeat center;
    position: relative;
}


#textContainer {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    color: yellow;
}
```

Also i'm enclosing fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vXzKc/

I appreciate every help!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, I'm quite confident you would at least have to know the height of your textcontainer. Then you could use a top/margin combination to solve this.

For what I know a table-cell is the only element that allows its content to be vertically aligned. I have no idea why, but this would allow you to make a little cheat by using display: table-cell

Here's my workaround:

HTML:

```
<div class="imgBaner">
    <div id="textContainer">
        Preparing for important meeting? <br />
        <b>Drink some coffeee!</b> <br />
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/me2octq.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgBaner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 460px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/5pijCrS.jpg) no-repeat center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#textContainer {
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vXzKc/1/

Note that display: table-cell may not work in old browsers or could cause different behaviour. I have tested it in the newest browers (IE, Firefox and Chrome) and it seemed to work in all of them.